# Pulling the id of a nested resource in a collection for the edit form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have two models:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scoreboard
end
```

and

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

On the **show** page of scoreboard, I have rendered the following:

```
<div class="all-teams"> 
  <%= render @scoreboard.teams %>
</div>
```

which links to a partial in the teams directory which does the following:

```
<%= div_for team, :class => "team-list" do %>
  <div class= "boxin1"><%= team.name %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.win %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.loss %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.tie %></div>
  <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team.id) %> </span>
  <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary">Del</span>
<%end%>
```

Before I ask my question, I will also display the controller data for the relevant actions:

**The show action in scoreboard controller:**

```
def show
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by(params[:id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
end
```

**Important Note**
 There is a form that already exists on this scoreboard#show view page that makes a new team object and calls the team#new method and team#create method in the team controller. That is why there is a @team variable in the scoreboard#show method.

**The edit action in the teams controller**

```
def edit
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now this is my problem. Everytime a div is generated for each team, an edit button is generated beside that div as well which will take you to the edit view containing a form to edit that particular team. The **@scoreboard** in the edit link pulls the **:scoreboard_id** fine but it seems we are not able to pull the **:id** for each team in order for the edit link to work. Everytime, we try to access the view for **scoreboard#show** we get the following error:

**No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"teams", :id=>nil, :scoreboard_id=>"7"} missing required keys: [:id]**

How can we pull the :id for each team in the div_for?

Comment: From where the `team` variable come from? Is that the full code of the partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good chance you're passing a newly initialized team along with other scoreboard teams. Try rejecting new records before rendering your teams:

```
<div class="all-teams"> 
 <%= render @scoreboard.teams.reject(&:new_record?) %>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. Could you please explain the concept behind it? I didn't totally understand why it works.

Comment: You have `@scoreboard.teams.new` somewhere else on the page (probably in a form). When you call `@scoreboard.teams.new` it adds a newly initialized team to the scoreboard teams and when you pass `@scoreboard.teams` to the render, newly initialized team also gets passed but cannot be rendered properly because it doesn't have an id yet.